# Different RavenDB collections with documents of same type

Tags: collections, definition, ravendb

In RavenDB I can store objects of type Products and Categories and they will automatically be located in different collections. This is fine.

But what if I have 2 logically completely different types of products but they use the same class? Or instead of 2 I could have a generic number of different types of products. Would it then be possible to tell Raven to split the product documents up in collections, lets say  based on a string property available on the Product class?

Thankyou in advance.

**EDIT:**
I Have created and registered the following StoreListener that changes the collection for the documents to be stored on runtime. This results in the documents correctly being stored in different collections and thus making a nice, logically grouping of the documents.

```
public class DynamicCollectionDefinerStoreListener : IDocumentStoreListener
{
    public bool BeforeStore(string key, object entityInstance, RavenJObject metadata)
    {
        var entity = entityInstance as EntityData;
        if(entity == null)
            throw new Exception("Cannot handle object of type " + EntityInstance.GetType());
        metadata["Raven-Entity-Name"] = RavenJToken.FromObject(entity.TypeId);
        return true;
    }

    public void AfterStore(string key, object entityInstance, RavenJObject metadata)
    {

    }
}
```

However, it seems I have to adjust my queries too in order to be able to get the objects back. My typical query of mine used to look like this:

```
session => session.Query<EntityData>().Where(e => e.TypeId == typeId)
```

With the 'typeId' being the name of the new raven collections (and the name of the entity type saved as a seperate field on the EntityData-object too).

How would I go about quering back my objects? I can't find the spot where I can define my collection at runtime prioring to executing my query.

Do I have to execute some raw lucene queries? Or can I maybe implement a query listener?

**EDIT:**
I found a way of storing, querying and deleting objects using dynamically defined collections, but I'm not sure this is the right way to do it:

**Document store listener:**

(I use the class defined above)

**Method resolving index names:**

```
private string GetIndexName(string typeId)
{
    return "dynamic/" + typeId;
}
```

**Store/Query/Delete:**

```
// Storing
session.Store(entity);

// Query
var someResults = session.Query<EntityData>(GetIndexName(entity.TypeId)).Where(e => e.EntityId == entity.EntityId)
var someMoreResults = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<EntityData>(GetIndexName(entityTypeId)).Where("TypeId:Colors AND Range.Basic.ColorCode:Yellow)

// Deleting
var loadedEntity = session.Query<EntityData>(GetIndexName(entity.TypeId)).Where(e => 
e.EntityId == entity.EntityId).SingleOrDefault();
if (loadedEntity != null)
{
session.Delete<EntityData>(loadedEntity);
}
```

I have the feeling its getting a little dirty, but is this the way to store/query/delete when specifying the collection names runtime? Or do I trap myself this way?

Comment: Why would you have different types of products, but use the same class type? They don't seem so different then.

Comment: In my case, I'm working on a generic framework, where I have a class named Entity. On runtime, new entity types can be configured without creating new C#-classes and recompiling any code.

I have a property on an entity defining its type. The question can be summarized into a generic question, if I can tell raven DB to split documents into seperate collections based on a property instead of creating new classes and recompiling the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stephan,
You can provide the logic for deciding on the collection name using:

```
 store.Conventions.FindTypeTagName
```

This is handled statically, using the generic type.
If you want to make that decision at runtime, you can provide it using a `DocumentStoreListner`

Comment: Can you confirm that the way I handled the custom collection names is correct? Thankyou in advance :)